# WPF - bug in FlowDocumentScrollViewer.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5, flowdocumentscrollviewer

In .NET 4.5 added a new property [FlowDocumentScrollViewer.IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.isinactiveselectionhighlightenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)
When sets to true, displays selected text when the control does not have focus with a gray color.

And the bug is, when you scroll the document, the selection zone is not updated but remain gray place fixed.

I checked all later versions and the bug not fixed.

Comment: Two things I don't understand: a. What does it mean the selection zone remain gray place fixed? Does it remain in the same location when the text scrolls inside it? b. Why do you post this here and not in one of Microsoft's sites?

Comment: a. On you scroling, the selected text moves up and the gray area remains constant in its place, just try and see it. b. Maybe someone has a solution or a replacement for this property.